# Display non-ASCII characters from CSV file retrieved with d3.csv

Tags: csv, d3.js, encoding

I am loading a .csv file using d3.js that contains data in the following format:

> "region","party","Year=2014" "0114 Upplands Väsby","Moderaterna",28.4
>   "0114 Upplands Väsby","Centerpartiet",3.7 "0114 Upplands
>   Väsby","Folkpartiet",6.1 "0114 Upplands Väsby","Kristdemokraterna",4.5
>   "0114 Upplands Väsby","Miljöpartiet",6.8 "0114 Upplands
>   Väsby","Socialdemokraterna",30.3 "0114 Upplands
>   Väsby","Vänsterpartiet",5.8 "0114 Upplands
>   Väsby","Sverigedemokraterna",10.9

As you can see, there are some characters like "ä", "ö" in the data. When I read the data and display them on the page (using the google chrome), I see the following:

> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Moderaterna ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Centerpartiet ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Folkpartiet ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Kristdemokraterna ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Milj�partiet ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Socialdemokraterna ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** V�nsterpartiet ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** Sverigedemokraterna ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** �vriga partier ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** ogiltiga valsedlar ***
>
> 0114 Upplands V�sby *** ej r�stande ***

You can see that the special characters are replaced with question marks. How can I show the actual character as found in the dataset?

Comment: These characters are from another character set. To have them display the same for everyone they should be encoded as html entities. E.g. ä can be represented as &#228; in HTML (see http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should use language-agnostic character set. The industry is unanimous about using [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) for the purpose of multi-lingual (in the wide sense, everything that is using more than 7-bit ACSII data) applications. Here's quote from the Wikipedia page.

> Unicode is a computing industry standard for the consistent encoding, representation, and handling of text expressed in most of the world's writing systems.

Most common and size-efficient Unicode encoding for western languages is UTF-8. So the only thing you need to do is make you application encoding-consistent. That means that your HTTP resources should be encoded in UTF-8 and their metadata indicated as UTF-8. Most like you have incorrect metadata, so make sure you have:

- HTML meta tag for the page, `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
- HTTP header for the page, `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
- HTTP header for the csv file, `Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @user1355185 append round trip headers for HTML and CSV files to the question.